Requirement of using PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE when requesting USB Permission
I'm trying to give permissions to an connected USB Device using PendingIntent. However when using PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE, i get following warning:

Mutable implicit PendingIntent will throw an exception, follow either
of these recommendations: for an existing PendingIntent use
FLAG_NO_CREATE and for a new PendingIntent either make it immutable or
make the Intent within explicit

But if i use PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE, it will never allow me to get permissions for the attached USB Device
What should i do now?
The code i use now:
 val permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)
 mManager?.requestPermission(device, permissionIntent)


Use PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE instead.
FYI check this: USBMonitor#register
Update 1 ------
Just use PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE and set package to your intent.
Like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77691737/23272559

Have you even read my question?

Sorry, I just went straight to your code.
Use PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE is working, then for the warning, set package to your intent. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77688241/requesting-usb-permission-has-been-failed-on-android-14-xamarin
